# Free or cheap Media(image) hosting for web application

Tags: web-applications

I am building a small social web application. I am developing it with rails. I want some cheap or free image hosting which I can use as my image repository for my website because I can't afford Amazon cloud store or something like that. Can I use flickr, imageshack or service something like that? Do they allow me to store images for my website? Suppose I wanna use pics for blogpost and I will be extracting pics from their api and show on my blog post. Is that possible? Sorry I'm beginner.

Comment: have you tried that question in google, there are many alternatives.  

It also depend on the use of the images and the number of request, if you can provide more details, it would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 : Cheap Shared Hosting (Why not just start with it and worry about network usage later?)

Option 2 : Use IMGUR.com ! Its free for non commercial use and has an API.
More : http://api.imgur.com

Comment: has limits, even for non commercial uses

Answer (score 1):

Is the API service needed for remote uploads and to let users upload images? If you plan to use images for blogspot or another blog whey not use their service to handle the images? You can signup with any one of the many unlimited shared hosting companies which have great storage space.

Amazon also has a free for 1 year micro instance. Space is limited but should be enough to get you started.

But from reading your question about a blog post and images. I would just setup an account on blogspot and upload images to my posts and pages using their interface. Not sure though what specific requirements your rails app needs though?

Comment: Hi there, I was just giving example about blog post. My app might have around 20000 users (really hope so). SO, it will be bit network heavy so shared hosting might not help as u said. It would be so good if I could upload to flickr pragmatically and show in my site all pictures.

Comment: Everyone hopes to have many people user their app. Reality is once you build it unless it goes viral or has a very big marketing budget you won't get to that many users too soon. So you have time to grow. Flickr has an API to use http://www.flickr.com/services/api/ Good luck.